# I want to retain the UIViewTable contents/Cells between segue exit and enter

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I really need someones help here.

I am creating simple chat application. I have single view controller with list of users listed in it. And on selecting one of the user cell it shows the chat window by loading 
the history of chat(through prepareForSegue).

Now close the chat window and move back to user list View controller window and then select again the user cell to show again the same chat window. 
**Here is the problem,**

> the chat View controller reloads again the data from chat history.

But I want the chat View controller to retain the data or view which shown last time without reloading or creating table cells.

Can anyone tell me is their any way I can accomplish this?

Below is the code snippet of segue,

```
- (void)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
    XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [[self fetchedResultsController]  objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    _currentChatWith = user.jidStr;
    _isChatting = YES;
    [_tableView setEditing: NO animated: NO];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"chatSegue" sender: self];
}



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma -mark prepareForSegue
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"chatSegue"])
   {
        ChatViewController *chatViewController = (ChatViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        chatViewController.appDelegate = [self appDelegate];
        chatViewController.rosterJid = _currentChatWith;
        chatViewController.isGroup = NO;
        _currentChatViewController = chatViewController;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to keep that kind of view state in your app. What is the reason or problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: it is some what like Whatsapp behavior. if you see in Whatsapp if I select user to chat, Chat screen will be shown now, I send some video where a progress of video upload will be shown now I exit the chat view and go back to users view. Now if I again select for chat viewer the same window is retained without reloading or creating new one(I think). So I also need some what similar behavior.    Thanks in advance